# create a flat list columnwise from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

I want to create a flat list column wise i.e:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I have achieved that using some loops and list comprehension, but I was wondering if there is any other method which can be more neat and concise than this:

```
l = []

for column in df:
    colobj = df[column]
    l.append(colobj.values.tolist())

flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
print(flat_list)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the values column-wise, you could transpose the DataFrame and access the values like so:

```
>>> [item for sublist in df.T.values for item in sublist]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Alternatively, you could use `reshape`:

```
>>> df.T.values.reshape(-1).tolist()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pandas methods, then `unstack` and call `to_list`:

```py
>>> df.unstack().to_list()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or, you can use [`numpy.ndarray.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) (May provide better performance for larger data):

```py
>>> df.values.ravel('F').tolist()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: nice one,thanks. one question ? What is `'F'` in `df.values.ravel('F').tolist()`

Comment: That is the value passed to `order` parameter for `np.ravel`, the value `F` means arrange the values in columnar order. Default value is `C` which means row-wise. You can take a look at [`np.ravel` documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel) to know more about the values for `order` parameter.